# iron-selector / app-route: strange behaviour

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm facing the problem, that the routing inside my application doesn't work correctly... for a better readability, I omit some code that isn't neccessary for now and I renamed my elements. Let's first have a look at the code, I'll address the problem afterwards:

*my-custom-frame.html*

```
...
<app-location route="{{route}}" use-hash-as-path></app-location>
<my-application route="{{route}}"></my-application>
...
```

*my-application.html*

```
...
<iron-selector selected="{{pageData.page}}" attr-for-selected="name" fallback-selection="home">

  <paper-icon-item name="home">
    <iron-icon src="/images/icon_home.png" item-icon slot="item-icon"></iron-icon>
  </paper-icon-item>

  <paper-icon-item name="subpage">
    <iron-icon src="/images/icon_subpage.png" item-icon slot="item-icon"></iron-icon>
  </paper-icon-item>

</iron-selector>
...

<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:page" data="{{pageData}}" tail="{{pageTail}}"></app-route>

...
<iron-lazy-pages id="pages" load-async="true" class="fit" selected="[[pageData.page]]" attr-for-selected="data-page" restamp="true">
  <template data-page="home" is="iron-lazy-page" path="{{resolveUrl('../home-view.html')}}">
    <home-view></home-view>
  </template>
  <template data-page="subpage" is="iron-lazy-page" path="{{resolveUrl('../subpage-view.html')}}">
    <subpage-view></subpage-view>
  </template>
</iron-lazy-pages>
...
```

And inside `home-view` and `subpage-view` I also have a `app-route` element that handles the pagetail, like here in the `subpage-view`:

*subpage-view.html*

```
...
<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:page" data="{{routeData}}" tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>
...
```

**Now the problem:**

When the user enters the page, he gets redirected to `#/home` (I have an observer in `my-custom-frame` that observes `route` and sets `route.path` to `home` if it's empty - also I do have the fallback in `iron-selector`):

*my-custom-frame.html*

```
Polymer({
    is: "my-custom-frame"
    properties: {
        route: {
            type: Object,
            observer: 'routeChanged',
            notify: true
        }
    },
    _checkRoute: function() {
      if (this.route.path === '') {
        this.set("route.path", "/home");

      }

    },
    onRouteChanged: function() {
      this._checkRoute();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine for now. If the user now clicks on the `subpage`-icon, he gets redirected to `#/subpage` and inside the `subpage-view` I also observe `route` and redirect him to `#/subpage/list`. That also works fine, as long as he stays in the `subpage`-context. 
Means, if he clicks on the `home`-icon, he gets redirected to `#/home/list`, but `home-view` doesn't have any routing logic. It's just a static page without observers, listeners or anything else.

After that, nothing really works anymore and the user is forced to reload the page or to manually cut off the trailing url part (`/list`) in order to navigate through the page again.

I'm searching for a solution for hours and days now, but I can't figure it out...

Feel free to ask any questions if my explanation is like a mystery ;-)

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

**UPDATE**

I reduced my code a minium, but a working example. 
You can checkout the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/sebastianroming/so-polymer-test), run `polymer serve` and reproduce with:

1. Open `http://localhost:8080`
2. **Home** is selected.
3. Click on **Subpage**, the URL changes to `#/subpage/childone/list` as expected
4. Click on **Home**, the URL changes to `#/home`, as expected
5. Click on **Subpage** again and see, the URL changes to `#/home/childone/list`

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to explain what you're actually trying to achieve? You know, on a more abstract, less technical level.

Comment: A correct routing ;-) See the update on the bottom of my question. I want the application to always route to '#/home' when clicking on the home-icon, and always to '#/subpage' when clicking on the subpage-icon. But that doesn't work properly, as described.

Comment: I guess you could handle #/home/list (or something more generic, using a regexp) in `_checkRoute()` and strip the "/list"-part there.

Comment: It's not about the trailing part... The steps to reproduce say: if you go from `home` to `subpage`, then back to `home` and THEN AGAIN back on `subpage`, the route isn't updated correctly.

Comment: Debugging tip: create an observer for `'[observerName](pageData.*)'` and set a breakpoint there. So you see what is actually going on with your bound property subpaths, which gives you a better chance of tracking the error, even within framework/3rd party components.

Comment: Actually `pageData.page` shows correctly `subpage`, but the URL reflects `#/home/childone/list`. That's incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself now (and it was - honestly - really easy):

In my `subpage-view.html` I just have to replace the line

```
if(this.route.path === "") {
```

with this one:

```
if(this.route.path === "" && this.route.prefix === "/subpage") {
```

and then it works as expected.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change `this.set("route.path", "/home");` to `location.assign("#/home")`

Comment: Can you delay it with debounce() or setTimeout()? https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#common-utility-apis

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct approach. For the initial load of the application, it works and redirects perfectly to #/home. But then the malfunction starts...

Comment: Can you reduce your code into a minimum test case, and upload to github. Hope that will help people look into your problem. Thanks.